# listtransactions weird offset workflow

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I need to extract last wallet transaction. But seems  `listtransaction` has some wrong logic. When I perform this function

```
listtransactions '*' 50 9
```

it just return me first records not last. In my case I have 11 records, so it return me record 1 and 2, instead of 10 and 11 as I expected. Thus I get first two records instead of last. Maybe I understood something wrong or missed some other params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to extract last wallet transaction.

This will return last transaction in the wallet:

```
listtransactions "*" 1 0
```

For second last transaction:

```
listtransactions "*" 1 1
```

Last two transactions:

```
listtransactions "*" 2 0
```

---

Consider a wallet has 5 transactions.

`listtransactions` [LABEL] [COUNT] [SKIP]

| Skip | Tx |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Tx<sub>5</sub> [END] |
| 1 | Tx<sub>4</sub> |
| 2 | Tx<sub>3</sub> |
| 3 | Tx<sub>2</sub> |
| 4 | Tx<sub>1</sub> [START] |

If you *skip 0* and *count 1* in the above table you will get Tx<sub>5</sub>

If you *skip 0* and *count 2* in the above table you will get Tx<sub>4</sub> and Tx<sub>5</sub>

If you *skip 1*(Tx<sub>5</sub>) and *count 1* in the above table you will get Tx<sub>4</sub>

If you *skip 1*(Tx<sub>5</sub>) and *count 2* in the above table you will get Tx<sub>3</sub> and Tx<sub>4</sub>